# Oracle SQL To Select Month-Wise Products Count For Last 6 Months

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

**Requirement**

How can I select/get Month-Year (MON-YY) wise result for every product? 
I tried to write a query as:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  PRODUCT_CODE AS PRODUCT
    ,       EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (UPDATED_DATE))  AS month_num
    ,       PRODUCT_CODE
    FROM    Test_Pivot
)
PIVOT     (    COUNT (PRODUCT_CODE)
          FOR  month_num  IN (  1 AS jan,  2 AS feb,  3 AS mar,  4 As apr,  5 as may,  6 AS jun,
                                7 AS jul,  8 AS aug,  9 AS sep,  10 As oct,  11 as nov,  12 AS dec
                             )                             
          );
```

I am getting results, but it gives complete count irrespective of year. I am not sure how to modify SQL to restrict counts till last 6 months from current month. I want Months  columns to be dynamically displayed as 'MON-YY' instead of just 'MON' as described in sample format below

```
   PRODUCT  JAN-16  FEB-16  MAR-16  APR-16  MAY-16  JUN-16
-------------------------------------------------------------
      D        1       0       1       0       0       2
      A        1       0       2       0       4       1
      B        1       0       2       1       1       0
      C        0       0       1       0       4       1
```

- data in above sample is only for description, (June-16 being the current Month)

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Pivot (
  id            NUMBER,
  customer_id   NUMBER,
  product_code  VARCHAR2(5),
  quantity      NUMBER,
  Updated_date          date
);
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (1, 1, 'A', 10, sysdate);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (2, 1, 'B', 20, sysdate-50);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (3, 1, 'C', 30, sysdate-90);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (4, 2, 'A', 40, sysdate-75);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (5, 2, 'C', 50, sysdate-25);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (6, 3, 'A', 60, sysdate-20);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (7, 3, 'B', 70, sysdate-80);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (8, 3, 'C', 80, sysdate-40);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (9, 3, 'D', 90, sysdate-5);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (10, 4, 'A', 100, sysdate-35);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (11, 2, 'A', 40, sysdate-75);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (12, 2, 'C', 50, sysdate-25);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (13, 3, 'A', 60, sysdate-20);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (14, 3, 'B', 70, sysdate-80);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (15, 3, 'C', 80, sysdate-40);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (16, 3, 'D', 90, sysdate-5);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (17, 4, 'A', 100, sysdate-35);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (18, 3, 'B', 60, sysdate-400);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (19, 3, 'C', 70, sysdate-365);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (20, 3, 'D', 80, sysdate-450);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (21, 3, 'A', 90, sysdate-500);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (22, 4, 'A', 100, sysdate-555);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (23, 2, 'B', 40, sysdate-543);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (24, 2, 'B', 50, sysdate-150);
INSERT INTO Test_Pivot VALUES (25, 3, 'D', 60, sysdate-151);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  PRODUCT_CODE AS PRODUCT
    ,       EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (UPDATED_DATE))  AS year_num
    ,       EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (UPDATED_DATE))  AS month_num
    ,       PRODUCT_CODE
    FROM    Test_Pivot
)
PIVOT     (    
          COUNT (PRODUCT_CODE)
          FOR  (year_num, month_num)  IN (  
               (2016,1) AS jan_16, (2016,2) AS feb_16, (2016,3) AS mar_16,
               (2016,4) AS apr_16, (2016,5) AS may_16, (2016,6) AS jun_16,
               (2016,7) AS jul_16, (2016,8) AS aug_16, (2016,9) AS sep_16,
               (2016,10) AS oct_16, (2016,11) AS nov_16, (2016,12) AS dev_16
          )
);
```

You cannot make years and months to be "dynamically displayed" and "automatically adjusted to display only 6 last months" in a static SQL, PIVOT clause isn't dynamic, you must list all pairs of values: `(2014,1) ...... (2027,12)` in it.
However you can make a dynamic query (using dynamic SQL), but this is a separate topic beyond of this answer.

**====== EDIT =============**

If you want results for only 6 last months, and you don't want exact month names as column names (Feb, Apr etc.), then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  PRODUCT_CODE AS PRODUCT

    ,       EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (sysdate)) - EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (UPDATED_DATE))  AS month_num
    ,       PRODUCT_CODE
    FROM    Test_Pivot
    WHERE UPDATED_DATE >= trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )  - interval '6' month
)
PIVOT     (    
          COUNT (PRODUCT_CODE)
          FOR  (month_num)  IN (  
             0 as current_month, 
             1 as previous_month, 
             2 as two_months_bef_curr_month, 
             3  as three_months_bef_curr_month,
             4 as four_months_bef_curr_month, 
             5 as five_months_bef_curr_month
                             )                             
          );
```

Comment: I did realize that Pivot clause isn't dynamic.
Is there any way we can achieve the requirement without using Pivot ?

I am able to get last Month_Year results as in following SQL, but struggling how to use it.

   `select to_char( add_months( start_date, level-1 ), 'MON-YY' ) Month_Year
      from (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -5) start_date,
                   trunc(sysdate, 'MON') END_DATE
              from dual)
     connect by level <= months_between(
                           trunc(end_date,'MM'),
                           trunc(start_date,'MM') ) + 1;`